# How to find an area of part of an right angle triangle when it vertex is folded on to base?

Tags: geometry

> In right triangle $ABC$, with $AB = 44$ cm and $BC = 33$ cm, point $D$ lies on
>   side $BC$ so that $BD:DC = 2:1$. If vertex $A$ is folded onto point $D$ to create
>   quadrilateral $BCEF$, as shown, what is the area of triangle $CDE$?
>
> [image]

Comment: @an4s your question is reasonable, but it has been pretty much [banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=AE$.

Then we have $DE=x$, and $CE=55-x$.

From $BD{\;:\,}DC=2{\;:\,}1$, we get $DC=11$.

In triangle $ABC$, we have $\cos(C)=\frac{3}{5}$, and $\sin(C)=\frac{4}{5}$.

Applying the law of cosines to angle $C$ in triangle $DCE$, we get
$$x^2=11^2+(55-x)^2-2(11)(55-x)\bigl({\small{\frac{3}{5}}}\bigr)$$
which yields $x=25$, hence $CE=30$.

Then the area of triangle $DCE$ is
$$
\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)(DC)(CE)(\sin(C))
=
\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)(11)(30)\bigl({\small{\frac{4}{5}}}\bigr)
=
132
$$

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Can't we solve this without trigonometry?

Comment: Perhaps, but as you can see, the solution using mostly algebra, and just two trig formulas (the law of cosines, and the trig area formula) is already quite simple.

Comment: I can see a way to solve it using coordinates, and no trigonometry, but the solution I posted is simpler.

Comment: You should be aware that your question will probably get closed (and eventually deleted). For future questions, to defend against that, you need to show some attempt, or discussion of your ideas, rather than posting just the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using coordinates, which, while longer than the solution I posted earlier, avoids the use of trigonometry . . .

From $BD{\;:\,}DC=2{\;:\,}1$, we get $BD=22$, and $DC=11$.

Letting $f=BF$, we have $AF=44-f$.

By the symmetry of the reflection, we have $DF=DA$, hence $DF=44-f$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, we get
\begin{align*}
&BD^2+BF^2=DF^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(22)^2+f^2=(44-f)^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f={\small{\frac{33}{2}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
By the symmetry of the reflection, line segment $FE$ bisects line segment $AD$.

Since triangle $DFA$ is isosceles, it follows that line $FE$ is perpendicular to line $AD$.

Since the slope of line $AD$ is $-2$, it follows that the slope of line $FE$ is ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, hence the equation of line $FE$ is 
$$y={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}x+{\small{\frac{33}{2}}}$$

The slope of line $AC$ is $-{\large{\frac{4}{3}}}$, hence the equation of line $AC$ is 
$$y=-{\small{\frac{4}{3}}}x+44$$
Since $E$ is the point where line $FE$ intersects line $AC$, the coordinates of $E$ can be found by solving the system
$$
\begin{cases}
y={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}x+{\large{\frac{33}{2}}}\\[4pt]
y=-{\large{\frac{4}{3}}}x+44\\
\end{cases}
$$
which yields $E=(15,24)$.

Thus, in triangle $CDE$, the length of the altitude from $E$ is $24$, so the area of triangle $CDE$ is
$$\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)(DC)(24)=\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)(11)(24)=132$$